# Host computer freezes during use of whonix through Virtualbox, how could I for sure diagnose the issue?

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Kubuntu 21.04 currently,and I've noticed this issue only during the use of Whonix Virtual machine with the gateway & workstation running (the latest version as of writing), the host itself will freeze, only the mouse will work but nothing is clickable, my clock stop moving. Nothing within the GUI of desktop works, my keyboard works as far as turning on/off backlight and such. I am not sure of the specific cause of why it would occur. I can't seem to check dmesg logs as it seem as if its refreshed every reboot and after host freezes I can't pull it up. I don't believe it to be a virtualbox bug as it doesn't seem to appear in other VMs, only seems to do so in Whonix, as this issue appears randomly its hard to say for sure, but usually occurs within the first hour (Mostly 30 mins) after whonix startup. Issue has occured aross different whonix updates as well.

I just switched to a new computer in january this year, this was a fairly new one released in mid 2020 and so when I first got it there were driver issues within linux relating to the mouse (touchpad, or external mouses wouldn't work), which was fixed in the 5.10 lts release of linux kernel, so I had to upgrade to it for mouse to work. With Ubuntu 21.04 that comes with 5.11, that, and other operations such as brightness control are fixed but I am unsure if there may be some driver related issues that might be the cause of this bug, maybe within Whonix itself?
I thought it might be the nouveau drivers im using, last time I switched to the nvidia drivers (yes, I have an nvidia gpu) my display look as if it were zoomed in 3x from its default, icons were out of view and barely usable and my display resolution only had 1 choice listed, so i couldn't seem to use the nvidia drivers even if I wanted.

Can you tell me other ways of being able to diagnose the issue on my end, any such software that can capture system information and write it to file so that after I perform hard reset and get back on, I can review it?

Thank you

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: I had intentionally disabled swap by commenting it out in fstab. I had done this for a long time. During use of Whonix, it showed 5.5gb used out of total 15.6gb. From my understanding, swap is only used if ram is exceeded or comes close. I have swap disabled, to prevent sensitive data such as encryption keys by tools like luks & veracrypt from being swapped (written to disk). When using say a Windows 10 VM, it never crashes, or freezes the host and runs very fast off an ssd occupying even more ram and processors, so it wouldn't make sense that its over using system resources.